# Wordpress - Rewrite pagination URL to use parameters instead of pretty permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I am trying to use URL parameters for pagination within WordPress for a `custom post type`. The current URL is...

```
example.com/my_custom_post_type/page/2
```

And I am trying to make it look like this...

```
example.com/my_custom_post_type&page=2
```

I have tried to set a rewrite rule in my htaccess like so...

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

But this is not working for me, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: For WP you will need to use WP rewrite API for custom rewrites

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1&$2=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work this one out in the end by disabling the cononical redirect for pagination queries like this...

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function ( $redirect_url ) {

    if ( is_paged() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $redirect_url;

}, 10, 1 );
```